# Do I need to perform a SELECT query after executing a Query to modify my record(s) in order to view the changed results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, delphi, dataset

Each time I perform a query (INSERT, DELETE,UPDATE). After Do I need to do Select * From Table, so my info can be seen on the Grid control?

For example:

UniQuery1 is my dataset.
   I'm using a TDBADvListView control.

```
   UniQuery1.Close;

   UniQuery1.SQL.Clear;

   SQL_QUERY:= 'insert into ListaCamiones(Tablilla,Marca,Modelo,Color) Values ('
  +QuotedStr(a1)+','+
   QuotedStr(a2)+','+
   QuotedStr(a3)+','+
   QuotedStr(a4)+')';

   UniQuery1.SQL.Text := SQL_QUERY;

   UniQuery1.Execute;
```

Do I need to do, **Select * From ListaCamiones**;
   So I can see the information back on my TDBADvListView?

Comment: I've submitted an edit to your question to address the title specifically. I've also added my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is both yes and no!

Yes in that you do have to perform a SELECT query again in order to aggregate the modified recordset, no in that you don't have to perform the query as a separate execution.

If you append a *semicolon* at the end of your *INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE* query string, and immediately follow that by the desired *SELECT* query, your call to Execute will simultainiously update the records and aggregate the updated recordset for display.

Additionally, I would change the way you're building your SQL string too!

```
const
  INSERT_QUERY_STRING = 'INSERT INTO ListaCaminoes(Tablilla, Marca, Modelo, Color) VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s"); SELECT * FROM ListaCaminoes';

// Now inside your method
  UniQuery1.SQL.Text := Format(INSERT_QUERY_STRING, [a1, a2, a3, a4]);
  UniQuery1.Execute;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: OK I understand but, I found that for example when I'm dealing with a lot of rows (records), the software seems slow :(, because it takes some amount of time to populate the grid control. On the other way as far as I know Delphi is single thread and that's maybe is the problem?

Comment: You can run the queries themselves from another thread, but if you're relying on "data-aware controls" this would present many problems far beyond the scope of this question. What you may find helpful is to PAGE your grid using the SQL "LIMIT" directive. For example, at the end of the SELECT query, add " LIMIT 1, 100". This will aggregate only records 1 through 100. You can then have page numbers and change the start/end limit based on the selected page. It's one idea you might like :)

Answer (score 3):

In general, yes, because in my experience when you make database changes via SQL statements:

1. no database component automatically refreshes the query,
2. no database can refresh the data in your application when the data
   has changed in the database.

I recommend that you use a separate query component (UniQuery2) to execute your SQL statement. The you can use the ReQuery method of your Query to re-execute your original query (UniQuery1).  Depending on the database components you are using, your local cursor may be reset.

Alternately you can Append/Insert to add records and Edit to change records of UniQuery1.  This avoids the need to re-execute your original query because the changes are added to the dataset records buffered locally by the Query component.  But, re-executing the query is necessary to get records that were added/edited by other users since your query was last executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you just inserted the Information to the Database you have got it already!

In some SQL-Variants (in mySQL I am shure) you can have the command "insert_id()" from the API, that returns the AUTO_INCREMENT - value of the last inserted Dataset.

If you just want to get this ID, it is the way to go (on mySQL, like I said), but if you want to have other data you have to Query it again. In a combined query (like posted before) or in two seperate queries.

Glad to help!